# Difference between Agent User ID and user/ password while configuring replication agent AEM

Tags: replication, aem

What is the difference between **Agent User ID** (Settings tab)  and **User/Password** (Transport tab)? Please share the scenarios of both two when configuring the replicating agents in AEM.

Answer (score 1):

This is well documented in Adobe's documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/replication.html#Replication%20Agents%20-%20Configuration%20Parameters)

The context that is missing is to understand the how ACLs work, each user/group has certain privileges/rights; which outside normal CRUD operations include Read ACL, Edit ACL and Replicate. You can read about them [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/security.html#Permissions%20in%20AEM)

Now coming to your question, a replication agent has host configuration (the system on which it is setup) and target configuration (the system it connects to). ***Agent User ID*** is used for the host system while ***User/Password on transport tab*** is for the target system.

For a replication agent on author, the user used in ***Agent User Id*** must have read and replicate rights on all path that need to be processed where as user specified in ***User/Password on transport tab*** must have create/write access to replicate the content on Publish instance.